# How to autofill and verify an address in a TextEdit (or another View) in Android

Tags: java, android, coordinates, autofill, street-address

Im working on a Android application where I need to get an address (and in the future, find other address that are on a X distance from the first one, where X is another input from the user).

I was thinking on getting typing address, and from there get the latitude and longitude from Google Maps API. And last filter the close address with Haversine formula.

Maybe there is an easier way with another Google API to do all this? im just stuck on getting the address from the user so I can get the coordinates.

Thanks

Comment: I think the google maps api is quite a good choice. If you just want the user to pick an address, you could use the Google Places SDK too.

Comment: You might want to look into a service that can do reverse geocoding for your future feature. You could take the lat/lon of the first address, then calculate the lat/lon that is X distance, then use reverse geocoding to see what address is at that location